# Calculo en DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Compañeros tengo una duda, resulta que tengo la necesidad de hacer un campo calculado donde me sume los montos netos de mi facturación, solo que hay ocasiones donde puede que el numero de factura se repita pero solo debo de tomar un valor de la cantidad de veces que mi factura se repita. para hacer el calculo de la sumatoria.

Ejemplo:

```
factura # 1 $100
factura #2 $300
Factura #2 $300
factura #3 $200
Factura #4 $500
Total_Neto = $1100 (campo calculado)
```

Answer (score 0):

Así a bote pronto se me ocurre una fórmula sencilla

```
MontoTotal= SUMX(
    DISTINCT(Facturas[NumFactura])
    ,CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Facturas[Monto]))
)
```

Comment: Excelente maestro, muchas gracias por el aporte. me funciono de maravilla